# Store an NSString as a fixed length integer?

Tags: objective-c, string, cryptography, compression, nsstring

having a bit of trouble finding a solution to this.

I want to take a large ordered text file of words and create - in the same order - a text file of fixed length numeric values.

For example:

```
Input File           Output File

AAA          ->      00000001
AAH          ->      00002718
AAZ          ->      71827651
```

Initially it seemed a hash function would do the trick. However they are one way. Also perhaps they are a bit "heavyweight" for this. After all, I don't need any cryptography. Plus, it's a reference file. It will never change.

Any compression is a bonus not essential. That said, I don't want the file to get any bigger than it already is. Which is why I don't just want to write out the words as text but with fixed lengths.

So, bottom line; input is a NSString of variable length, output is an integer of fixed length. And, I must be able to take the integer and figure out the string.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks!
xj

Comment: And simply using the index/linenumber of the string in your array/file is not an option ?

Comment: using an array would mean having them in memory, and it's 270K words. The idea of having them in a file is I can seek to the appropriate word in the file without having them all in memory. To do that I need to know where to seek. For example let's say I want the fiftieth word. If the words are stored in fixed length format then I could navigate to that byte position. Line numbers would only be of use if the file had line breaks. That means parsing the file tokenising using those line breaks. That would take too long.

Comment: Then what about the file offset of the string ?

Comment: you mean store an offset for every string? That would work I guess but I'd need to store 270K offsets.

Comment: Yes, you will store the offsets in a file, and you can build several level of indices over the offsets (text prefix - offset in offsets). That's the normal solution. And you know how this is called? A database :)

Comment: the database solution is not fast enough. Even if you batch the fetches, you will get a UI hit as the user scrolls. Scanning through a fixed length files is much much faster. Normally "database" implies additional functionality over and above a data file on the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this would be a bit of a brute force method, but here's my guess.

Start by making a custom function to convert one letter of text to an integer less than 100. (I'm not sure if such a function already exists, if so then great!) You might need to just go to stuff like "if ([input isEqual: @"a"]){ return 1;}

Then, run that function on each letter of text, and get the final integer by combining the previous results.

For example:

int myVal1 = [intConverter firstLetter];
int myVal2 = [intConverter secondLetter];
int myVal3 = [intConverter thirdLetter];

int finalValue =100^3 + 100^2*myVal1 + 100*myVal2 + myVal3;

Then, finalValue would be of the form 1(myVal1)(myVal2)(myVal3), which is what I think you're looking for.

To get back the original string, simply use the mod (%) and division functions to get the individual values back, then run the intConverter function backwards. (This would probably mean writing a new function that basically runs those if statements in reverse, but oh well.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: pretty cool thanks. Strange there doesn't seem to be anything standard out there to do this.

Comment: well, a string is actually a number base 256 and you are limiting it to a subset of ASCII characters (using only first 100 chars) and making it a number base 100. Not a very cool solution.